# What are virtual ways to travel?

Tags: international-travel

I've been missing the experience of traveling due to the pandemic and I'm curious if there are other apps or websites etc such as this one https://driveandlisten.herokuapp.com/ (which allows people to take a virtual drive around a variety of cities around the world) that allow people to travel virtually.

Comment: Probably a bit broad, asking for a list of items is generally off topic (see the [help]).  However, try https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com/ - pretty wonderful.